# Why can I only unlock some elements in my master template in Adobe InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page, template-design, configuration

So I am using templates, and can override the locked master items (e.g. text boxes and headers) yet cannot seem to unlock an image (which I am using as a placeholder to replace with the correct image every time I use the template.)

On most items on the page, I unlock by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> and clicking on the the dotted outline of whatever it is; but for some reason I cannot get to the image.

**Why can't I unlock / alter the image element on my master page, and what can I do to make it possible?**

Comment: Is the layer locked?

Comment: sounds like some of layers are locked in the master file as Lauren has asked.  Can you check and let us know?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely sounds to me like the image placeholder is locked in the master page itself.

Double click on the relevant master page and select

> **Object/ Unlock all on spread**

from the top menu.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem working in InDesign CC.

Find the layers tab and see if this box is on the currently selected layer.

In my case it was on another layer and the layer was locked. Unlocking the layer sorted the problem.

Quite a headache!

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! Your answer should better be a comment, because you gave no more informations we can read in the older answer. I guess a moderator will change your answer to a comment soon (you can comment if you have earned more reputation ...).

Comment: @Kurt: As far as I can see (I am no Adobe user though), this should neither be a comment nor an answer, as it adds nothing to the existing content.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same. Problem.

I did not have anything locked, not on the layer or the spread.

I deleted any scripts I had loaded, and went through all of the trouble shooting steps (styles, fonts, preferences, etc.) from adobe.com, all to no avail.

Then for no reason I decided to ungroup everything I had grouped on my master page.

*Suddenly, Everything worked as expected.*

I hope this solves your problem. I was about five seconds from starting over.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative.

Select all pages in the 'Pages Panel'. right click and select 'Override all master page items'.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

To unlock everything, javasript would be a choice.

```
try {
    if (app.activeDocument) {
        app.activeDocument.layers.everyItem().locked = false;
        app.activeDocument.pageItems.everyItem().locked = false;
    }
} catch (err) {}
alert("Done!");
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a discrepancy between the suggested keyboard shortcut in the "Objects" dropdown menu and the actual keyboard shortcut.
It is not cmd+alt-L, but actually cmd+alt+shift-L. The shift key makes a world of difference.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/110226)